# How to get indexOf that matches this string from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

What I am trying to do is: Get **foobar** from an array if it contains **foo**

I usually just use *indexOf*, but this time I don't have the exact string and I don't know to make use of the *includes* function

Here is my code sample:

```
  var array = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
  var str = array.split(" ");
  var foobar = str.indexOf(this.includes("uni"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead, which returns the first item for which the given predicate returns `true`. In the event that no item in the array satisfies the predicate, the result of `.find()` will be *`null`*.

```js
var array = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var str = array.split(" ");
var foobar = str.find(word => word.includes("uni")); //Find first word that includes "uni"

console.log(foobar);
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. 
`word => word` is a loop right? since it returns the first item it finds, how do you make it start to look from the bottom/last?

Comment: this worked. 
`var foobar = str.reverse().find(word => word.includes("uni"));`

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the index if that is what you are looking for.

```
var array = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var str = array.split(" ");
var foobar = str.indexOf(str.find(word => word.includes("uni")));

console.log(foobar);
```

Comment: I think you should use `findIndex` instead of doing `indexOf` + `find`, its made for stuff like this